# adding zero decimal with java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code like this in my view:

```
<div id="price"> 2000000 </div>
```

I want a Javascript code that add "," for **each three digits from right** and in my code it's should be: 2,000,000

I'm beginner in javascript and i seen a few topics about this code and none of them was complete (with html codes) , please explain how i use this javascript code in my html code
How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: @MattGrande I'm beginner in java script i'm not sure to how use these javascripts code in my div id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleString()` method on a number in javascript, to get your required result.

```js
var priceDiv = document.getElementById("price")
var price = +priceDiv.innerHTML;
priceDiv.innerHTML = price.toLocaleString()
```

```html
<div id="price"> 2000000 </div>
```

More on `toLocaleString` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 1):

use `n.toLocaleString()`. it will convert number to comma separated number.

Comment: I'm beginner in java script i'm not sure to how use this javascripts code in my div id . please explain complete code . thanks